# Passing arbitrary text value to ruby controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, textbox

I know this is answered elsewhere, but I was looking and couldn't find what I needed.

I'm passing a value to a method that adds a value to a numeric attribute in the object.

I have a form, but I can't figure out how to give a textbox an arbitrary name and reference it in the view.  If I pass the textbox an arbitrary symbol, it looks for that attribute in the object.  I just need to name the textbox something random, and have the value pass to the controller action.  The textbox value should not be connected to anything on the object, any help?

The controller action (does nothing right now, waiting to figure out how to pass values):

```
  def addto(valu)
  end
```

The view form:

```
  <%= form_for(@cooler) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
         <%= f.label "Increase/subtract from value:" %><br />
         <%= f.text_field :dfdf%>
   </div>
   <p style="float:left;"><%= button_to "+", coolers_addto_path(:valu => 2)%></p>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters in controller, like this:

```
def addto
  # Here you can access your value with params[:val]
end
```

Comment: but how do i refer to the textbox in the view portion of things?, where it has the symbol :dfdf, how do i say coolers_addto_path(:dfdf)

Comment: Values of inputs are sent automatically through the form that they belong to.

Comment: I'm still having a problem on the view side, the button keeps referring to the update action, and I'm not sure why.   <p style="float:left;"><%= button_to "+", :action => "addto"%></p>.  In the HTML, the button says that the value is "+", and I think the value should be "addto", what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: also, the text field is formatted like this, but I still believe something is wrong with this as well <%= text_field(:post, :title=>:valu) %>

Comment: What do you want to do?
HTML buttom submits form. Form is submitted to URL referred in for tag. That's why you are lead to `update` action.